# The difference between audio file types

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using cocosDenshion with cocos2d to play sounds on the iPhone.
However, I need to find the best type of files that will play smoothly and efficiently.
Here are some file formats that I have so far: WAV, MP3, and CAF.
Should I convert these files all to a certain format? Are any one of them more efficient then the rest? Especially for sound effects, what should I use? And how about background music? Thank you!

Comment: be careful with .wav. It's not an audio format - it's a container that can contain all kinds of different audio formats. Parsing/reading .wav is the least of your problems - it's having codecs to handle all the different formats that are embeddable in .wav. And 'efficient' can mean many different things. File size? cpu required to decompress? audio quality vs file size? etc...

Comment: Marc is correct; however, it is most common to use WAV for uncompressed audio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/cocosdenshion%3afaq#what_sound_formats_can_i_use), this is what I'm doing for my game:

MP3 for background music.

"16 bit mono wave files" for sound effects.

Comment: This is not a bad rule of thumb, but it depends. You might have stereo sound effects, in which case you should use stereo format for your sound effects. If you have a lot of sound effects, you may want to store them in a compressed format, and decompress them "as needed" (really before you need them, so you don't incur a delay) I don't know if that applies to cocos.